# 2sxc - Getting URL path from DNN link parameter / Tab ID

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I am working on integrating a 2sxc content WebAPI feed into a ReactJS application.

I have managed to get a JSON feed of data into the application, and am in the process of mapping out the data.

I'm wondering what the best practice would be to "resolve" a URL which is coming through as a DNN Page/ Tab ID.

Below I will showcase the various points this is referenced...

First the Setup of the entity / data types...

[image: Data Types]

Then this is an example entry with the data filled out... The page link / URL is set up to point to another internal page on the DNN website:

[image: Item]

Finally you can see this data item come through as a JSON feed via the 2sxc API:

[image: API Feed]

**What is the best way to convert this piece of data into a URL which can be used in a SPA type application?**

There isn't any "server-side" code going on, just reading a JSON feed on the client side...

My initial idea would be to parse this piece of data in JS, to extract the number then use something like this:

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/85/default.aspx

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/default.aspx?tabid=85

I was hoping someone with more experience would be able to suggest a better / cleaner approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you were server-side in Razor you'd be doing something like this:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Common

    <a href="@Globals.NavigateURL(XXXX, "", "Dept=" + deptQS, "View=List")">View List</a>
```

XXXX = Dnn.Tab.TabID or define a string with the tab id you want

I seem to have a vague memory that I saw somewhere that Daniel (2sxc) has a way to use Globals.NavigateUrl() or similar on the client side, but I have no idea where or if I did see that.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could track down the client-side version. I am quite comfortable using Razor syntax. But this is a plain "HTML" or "Token" template which is using React.

Comment: Sorry, I am guessing my memory was wishful thinking. If it is in there, I have not found it. maybe we need to get this in front of Daniel as a feature request? There has been recent work on $2sxc.cms.run() - this seems like it might somehow fit in with that effort, maybe.

Comment: The (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/default.aspx?tabid=85) format works fine... But I can't speak with confidence that this is the best method.

Answer (score 1):

The `Default.aspx?tabid=xx` format will certainly work, as it's the oldest DNN convention and is still used in fallbacks. The urls aren't nice, but it's ok.

The reason you're seeing this is because the query doesn't perform the automatic lookup with the `AsDynamic(...)` does for you. There is an endpoint to look them up, but they are not official, so they could change and therefor I don't want to suggest that you use them.

So if you really want a nicer url, you should either see if DNN has a REST API for this, or you could create a small own 2sxc-api endpoint (in the `api` folder) just to look that up, then using the NavigateURL. Would be cool if you shared your work.

Comment: The client is happy with the  Default.aspx?tabid=xx  format - As it does remap to a friendly url... I will probably be using this type of ReactJS / 2sxc content module more frequently - So I will update here if anything improves.